# how can I get the count of non zero at each row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I'm using pandas

dataframe is like

```
name data1 data2 data3
kim   0 1 1
yu    0 1 1
min   2 0 0
```

I want to filter, if there are more than 2 data values ​​greater than 0 for each row (filter kim, yu)

Is it possible to do this with pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with get necssary rows by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) by columns names, or by position by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) (all columns without first) or numeric columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html).

Then compare if greater like `0`, count values by `sum` and compar if greater or equal `N`:

```
N = 2
out = df.loc[df.filter(like='data').gt(0).sum(axis=1).ge(N), 'name']
out = df.loc[df.iloc[:, 1:].gt(0).sum(axis=1).ge(N), 'name']
out = df.loc[df.select_dtypes(np.number).gt(0).sum(axis=1).ge(N), 'name']
```

---

```
print (out)
0    kim
1     yu
Name: name, dtype: object
```

EDIT: For all rows use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
N = 2
out = df[df.filter(like='data').gt(0).sum(axis=1).ge(N)]
out = df[df.iloc[:, 1:].gt(0).sum(axis=1).ge(N)]
out = df[df.select_dtypes(np.number).gt(0).sum(axis=1).ge(N)]
```

Another idea is create index by `name` column, ouput is filtered indices:

```
df1 = df.set_index('name')
N = 2
out = df1.index[df1.gt(0).sum(axis=1).ge(N)]
print (out)
Index(['kim', 'yu'], dtype='object', name='name')
```

Comment: Can I ask How can I get the "all data" in the row not only the "name"?

Comment: @Shale - Added `EDIT` to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['kim', 'yu', 'min'],
    'data1': [0, 0, 2],
    'data2': [1, 1, 0],
    'data3': [1, 1, 0],
})

df = df.set_index('name')

df.loc[
    (df > 0).sum(axis=1) >= 2
].reset_index()
```